# MyRepos (MR) default configuration

Tags: git, configuration

I am running MR ([myrepos](http://myrepos.branchable.com/)) and trying to get global configuration running. I've attempted at using the DEFAULT section in the .mrconfig with no avail like so:

```
[DEFAULT]
clean = git clean -df
st = git status
```

When I type something like "mr cl" it will error and suggest using "clean" tag, so it's aware of it. But when I use "mr clean" it will just output "mr clean: no defined action for git repository /home/scriptss/www/wp1, skipping"

If I use the same code on the registered repos like specified below, it will work.

```
[/home/scriptss/www/wp1]
st = git status
```

I just don't want to define the same actions for every repo as there will be a lot of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you should write your commands in ./mrconfig is:

```
[DEFAULT]
git_clean = git clean -df
git_status = git status
```

This is due to myrepos doing different actions depending on the type of the repo, so in the main `.mrconfig` file it will need to know the type of the repo, while in the `.mrconfig` file in the specific repo already know if it is a git or another kind of version control system.